# Java : JList only finds indices in visible range

Tags: java, actionlistener, jlist, visible

I have the following code execute on button click :

```
while(count<listAmount){
        tbiCList.setSelectedIndex(0);

        String item = JList.getSelectedValue();

            String update[] = item.split(", ");

            //this part removed for sake of post

        remove(item);
        count++;
    }
```

Notes:

`count` starts as 0, `listAmount` is the amount of items in `JList`, and `remove()` is a method I have that removes the selected item.

This all works fine and dandy, BUT, the problem is, it only selects and removes the items that are visible when the button is clicked, and not the items that are past the scroll pane. Of course, I could just click the button again, and get the next set of items, but, I'm a programmer and I want the **simplest** way of completing my task.

**UPDATE**

I realized that I'm setting `listAmount` by getting `LastVisibleIndex();`

My bad.

My question now : How to retrieve `listAmount` every time the `while` command updates?

**UPDATE TO THE UPDATE**

Because I'm impatient, I tend to do this a lot, so, I apologize.

I figured out how to fix my problem. Inside the `while` loop I just added +1 to the `listAmount` variable and then when it gave me the `NullPointerException` I added a `try` block around the `while` block. So that is that, problem fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `getSelectedValue()` to get a single selection you could remove the while statement and use `getSelectedValuesList()` instead to select multiple items then iterate through those.

Don't forget to check the JavaDoc for other options.

Edit for comment:

```
List<String> selectedItems = myJList.getSelectedValuesList();
for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++){
    String item = selectedItems.get(i);
    String update[] = item.split(", ");
    //this part removed for sake of post
    //....
}
myJList.removeAll();
```

Comment: In response to your edit: To get a new listAmount just use the same method as you used to get it the first time but put it inside your while loop?

Comment: The problem there is that I can't put the variable inside the loop because the while loop **uses** that variable. But I actually figured out how to do it. Editing question now...

Comment: And I'm sure your answer might just help, but the problem is : I need to select the values one by one, assign them to the same string, so I can use it for the SQL query. I appreciate you trying to help though! :D

Comment: Hmm, the new approach is not the best practice, there are more simple ways to do it, I can offer a suggestion but: What is the intent of your code? It seems like it has 3 parts: 1) Grab every item on the list 2) Run some code on every item 3) Remove every item from the list. Is that correct? See my edit suggesting a way to do that.

Comment: It's an inventory program. When I add an object to the list, it's in the format of "quantity, item, price" and an example would be like "1, DrPepper, 1.0" and it splits the string, subtracts the quantity from the item in an SQL database, and adds the price to my profit database. I figured there would be a way to use the list model for an array of some sort, but, my code works and I'll leave it at this point, one more function and I'm done with the program. I really appreciate all your help, though, and I'll keep your answer in mind for later reference. :)